# stratified sampling or proportional sampling in R

Tags: r

I have a data set generated as follows:

```
myData <- data.frame(a=1:N,b=round(rnorm(N),2),group=round(rnorm(N,4),0))
```

The data looks like as this

[image]

I would like to generate a stratified sample set of `myData` with given sample size, i.e., 50. The resulting sample set should follow the proportion allocation of the original data set in terms of "group". For instance, assume `myData` has 20 records belonging to group 4, then the resulting data set should have `50*20/200=5` records belonging to group 4.  How to do that in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [my `stratified` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112), specifying a value < 1 as your proportion, like this:

```
## Sample data. Seed for reproducibility 
set.seed(1)
N <- 50
myData <- data.frame(a=1:N,b=round(rnorm(N),2),group=round(rnorm(N,4),0))

## Taking the sample
out <- stratified(myData, "group", .3)
out
#     a     b group
# 17 17 -0.02     2
# 8   8  0.74     3
# 25 25  0.62     3
# 49 49 -0.11     3
# 4   4  1.60     3
# 26 26 -0.06     4
# 27 27 -0.16     4
# 7   7  0.49     4
# 12 12  0.39     4
# 40 40  0.76     4
# 32 32 -0.10     4
# 9   9  0.58     5
# 42 42 -0.25     5
# 43 43  0.70     5
# 37 37 -0.39     5
# 11 11  1.51     6
```

Compare the counts in the final group with what we would have expected.

```
round(table(myData$group) * .3)
# 
# 2 3 4 5 6 
# 1 4 6 4 1 
table(out$group)
# 
# 2 3 4 5 6 
# 1 4 6 4 1
```

---

You can also easily take a fixed number of samples per group, like this:

```
stratified(myData, "group", 2)
#     a     b group
# 34 34 -0.05     2
# 17 17 -0.02     2
# 49 49 -0.11     3
# 22 22  0.78     3
# 12 12  0.39     4
# 7   7  0.49     4
# 18 18  0.94     5
# 33 33  0.39     5
# 45 45 -0.69     6
# 11 11  1.51     6
```

Comment: Ananda, thanks for your reply. I have a question regarding your code  temp <- lapply(
    names(df.split),
    function(x) df.split[[x]][sample(df.table[x],
                                     n[x], replace = replace), ]) Looks like you were doing sampling with replacement. This potentially can cause duplicate samples. Is that right?

Comment: @user288609, what's the question? :-) All the code up to that point is to determine the sample sizes per strata. That is the stage at which the sampling actually takes place. It cycles through a `data.frame` that has been split by group, and samples the required number of rows from each subset.

Comment: @user288609, no. Not unless `replace = TRUE` when you call the function. (Sorry, your question wasn't there when I started writing my comment.)

Comment: Thanks, just for clarification,in your code, you have replace=replace, which is equivalent to replace = FALSE. is that right?

Comment: Or in other words, I changed your code of sample(df.table[x], n[x], replace = replace), ]) to sample(df.table[x], n[x], replace = FALSE), ])   they are the same. Is my understanding right? Thanks

Comment: @user288609, Why aren't you just using the preset arguments available for the function? The arguments are `df`, `group`, `size`, `select` (set to `NULL`), `replace` (set to `FALSE`), and `bothSets` (set to `FALSE`).

Comment: Oh, I see, the replace is a parameter. I did not check your example very clearly, and just dig into the code. Thank you!

Comment: I know this is six years later, but I have a question about the function: Are you able to pass multiple grouping variables to it? I've tried using ```group = c("group1","group2")``` but it didn't work.